# how to pass datalabels along with data to show it in tooltip in highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using column with drilldown highchart.

```
 series: [{
                    name: 'Attendance',
                    colorByPoint: true,
                    data: [{
                        name: 'Jan',
                        y: Attendances.data.YearlyReport[0],
                        drilldown: 'Jan',
                    }, ...]
                }],  
  drilldown: {
                    series: 
                        [{
                        name: 'Jan',
                        id: 'Jan',
                        data: [
                            [
                                '1',
                                parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 1])

                            ],
                            [
                                '2',
                                  parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 2])
                            ],
                            [
                                '3',
                                  parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 3])
                            ],
                           ...
                        ]}, 
                        {
                        name: 'Feb',
                        id: 'Feb',
                        data: [
                               ....
```

I want to pass some string to each drilldown series data i.e

```
'1',
 parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1      *  33 + 1])
```

I want to attach some more info to 1 and then show it in tooltip. How can it be possible?

Answer (score 2):

For your data point set the data as a point [object](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series%3Cline%3E.data):

```
[
    {
        x: '1',
        y: parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 1]),
        yourNote: 'some text you want to add'
    },
    {
        x: '2',
        y: parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 2]),
        yourNote: 'some other text you want to add'
    },
...
]
```

Then, in your tooltip, use [`formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) to display the `yourNote` property:

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: function() {
    console.log(this); //so you can see what other properties exist
    if (!this.point.yourNote) {
      return 'The value for <b>' + this.x +
        '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>';
    } else {
      return 'The value for <b>' + this.x +
        '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>' +
        '<br />' + this.point.yourNote;
    }

  }
},
```

You can call the property `yourNote` anything you like as long as it is not going to collide with reserved property names. Generic demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/farnubc5/). Hover mouse over first point.